# How do I separate the choices in a list

Tags: java, swing, jlist

The purpose of the program is to calculate the volumes of different geometrical figures (Like a cylinder or a pyramid). I've started out by adding a list where the user can choose between the different figures.

The problem is that I don't know how to make the program know which formula to use. I need to be able to separate the choices instead of just making an int out of the answer.

```
    private void btnAktiveraActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        String form = listForm.getSelectedValue().toString();
        int fo = Integer.valueOf( form );

        String höjd = txfHöjd.getText().toString();
        int hö = Integer.valueOf( höjd );

        String bredd = txfBredd.getText().toString();
        int br = Integer.valueOf( bredd );

        String radie = txfRadie.getText();
        int ra = Integer.valueOf(radie);

        String djup = txfDjup.getText();
        int dj = Integer.valueOf(djup);

        double ACyl = 3.14*ra*ra*hö;
        double APyr = (br*dj*hö)/2;
        double AKub = br*dj*hö;
        double ARät = br*dj*hö;

        txfHöjd.setEnabled(false);
        txfBredd.setEnabled(false);
        txfDjup.setEnabled(false);
        txfRadie.setEnabled(false);
        listForm.setEnabled(false);
    }                                           

    private void btnBeräknaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // I know this code won't work, its just a reminder.
    if (answer == Cyinder){
        System.out.print("volymen är: "+ACyl+" cm^3");
    }            

    }
```

Comment: Since the user somehow makes a choice you get some feedback. Use that feedback to determine which choice the user made and use `switch` or `if` to select the corresponding formula.

Comment: Well, yes of course. But do you know the code to write when I want to retrieve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the list for the user to choose from, maybe consider a map instead. You can have all your shapes as the keys of the map and then the formulas for volume as the values of the map. The list of shapes can be provided to the user via the keySet and their response can be matched back against the map to find the formula.

EDIT: You have your formulas for each shape inside an action event. You'll need to move those into a separate class

```
public static class Formulas() {
     // list all formulas here
     private String cylinder = "3.14*r*r*h";
}
```

Then when you hit the action you can either create a new instance of the Formulas class and use any convenience methods you might write in there.

Comment: I want something like: "If the selected figure = "pyramid", print out (volume of pyramid)". Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, and could be achieved in one line. Something of the nature: System.out.println("Formula for Volume of Pyramid " + mapObj.get(userAnswer));

Comment: That could at least print out the formula if you had it in String format. If you want to actually print the value of the volume then I think you've oversimplified the issue. At that point you'll want to look at an interface for geometrical shapes and multiple implementations of that interface to calculate the volume.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question very clearly. I would suggest to make a plan to solve your problems.

1. make a list of figures that program will calculate
2. make a list of methods to count volumes of those figures
3. create individual classes, variables etc...
4. create methods
5. create main method with user input

You mentioned you don't know which formula to use. **I assume there won't be many formulas in your program.** I would create an individual method for each individual figure i.e. piramidFormula(), cilinderFormula()...

There is no point to refer to polimorphism when I think your level of programming is very basic at this stage.

I hope that will help you a little bit.

Comment: My main problem is that i don't know how to get the program to know witch formula that goes with witch answer from the list. Right now i have just made int of the answer but all answers have different formulas to calculate the volume.

Comment: It is very hard @Crocus to help you without reading your code. Can you add your code to your question ?

Comment: Absolutly. It's there now.

Answer (score 0):

You need a list to hold the things, you seem to understand this just fine.

You need a way to select things.  Selection is typically not exactly the same thing as the list, you need a class to be responsible for the "selection" behaviour.

Each thing has a routine that can calculate the volume.  That means it will need input parameters.  This is where it starts to get tricky, because if you want all of your things to be in the same list, you need to decide how to manage the different input parameters for the different *types* in the list.

```
public List<VolumeCalculations> volumeCalculations ...

public interface VolumeCalculation {
   public double getVolume();
}

public class CubleCalcuation implements VolumeCalculation {
   private double side = 0;

   public void setSide(double value) {
     this.side = value;
   }

   @Override
   public double getVolume() {
     return side*side*side;
   }

}
```

the other volume calculations are left as an exercise to you.

Then you need to put them all in the list

```
volumeCalculations.add(new CubeVolumeCalculation());
...
```

But when you select the calculation, you will need "something" to ask for the right input.

```
public interface CalculationInputGather {
   public void setCalcualtion(VolumeCalcuation value);
   public void askForInputs();
}
```

which the one for the CubleCalcuation might look like

```
public CubeInputGather implements CalculationInputGatherer {

   @Override
   public void setCalculation(VolumeCalcualtion value) {
     if (value instanceof CubeCalcuation) {
       this.volume = value;
     }
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("value must be a CubeCalculation");
   }

   public void askForInputs() {
     System.out.println("enter the side value:");
     // read the value
     volume.setSide(value);
   }
}
```

then when you know the selected item in the list, you can use a Map of Calcuations to their input gatherers to lookup the right input gatherer for the selected calcuation.